# Nested for loops and break

Tags: nested, break

Why does the following code not print anything? The first set of values of a and b that satisfies the condition is a = 1 and b = 4. However, I don't see that being printed.

```
def fun():
    for a in range(5):
        for b in range(5):
            if a + b == 5:
                print(a,b)
                break
            break

fun()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `break`, as the first one will terminate the innermost loop,  allowing to increment the outermost (value of a) which is what you want. Breaking twice terminates the whole execution so your code should look like this:

```
def fun():
    for a in range(5):
      for b in range(5):
          if a+b ==5:
              print(a, b)
              break
fun()
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to display the first set of values then instead of `break` it's a `return` that is needed to terminate the whole execution.

```
def fun():
    for a in range(5):
      for b in range(5):
          if a+b ==5:
              print(a, b)
              return
fun()
```

Comment: But I would like to terminate both loops after obtaining a= 1 and b= 4. Also, I tried running your suggested code and it prints out 4 sets of values of a and b, not just one set

Comment: You can simply achieve that by replacing `break` by `return` in the code snippet I posted. This allows you to stop everything once the condition is met.

Comment: Oh that's an intelligent solution

Comment: Here is a useful resource to visualize the difference between `break`, `return` and `continue` : https://www.learnpython.dev/02-introduction-to-python/110-control-statements-looping/40-break-continue/